# Getting Error Code 200 while logging into PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Getting this error while logging into MySQL through PHPMyAdmin

[image]

When logged in through SQL Workbench no issues.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have a steady internet connection?

Comment: [https://bobcares.com/blog/phpmyadmin-error-code-200/](https://bobcares.com/blog/phpmyadmin-error-code-200/)

Comment: Does this only happen when you're first logging in or is there some other tab you go to first? Please tell us about your PHP, MySQL, and web server versions. Is the MySQL server running on the same machine as the webserver? Is there anything logged in the webserver error log?